# ItemizedOverlay and custom marker on OsmDroid for Android, no more touch event

Tags: android, touch, marker, osmdroid

I'm curently using a class which extends from the Drawable on OsmDroid.
And on this class I draw a geometric form for each car I receive from internet.
I would like to add a listener on each car in order to give some informations when we touch the car.
With a OverlayItem we can do this :

```
ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
carOverlay.draw(new Canvas());
overlayItem = new OverlayItem("test", ""+i, geoPoint);
overlayItem.setMarker(carOverlay.getCurrent());
items.add(overlayItem);
ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> overlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(this.getApplicationContext(), items,
        new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                Log.i("Touch","you just tap the car");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                return false;
            }

        });
```

With this piece of code, I can see the image I've just drawn, but no event when I touch a car, and if I remove the line :

```
overlayItem.setMarker(carOverlay.getCurrent());
```

to let the default marker being displayed instead of my custom marker, the touch events occure.

So what am I doing wrong ? must be the same no ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 'proper' answer but as I am facing similar problem I resorted to using BOTH default draw and custom at the same time.
I just call super() at the end of my custom draw method on ItemizedIconOverlay and both my drawing and 'default' item marker are drawn.
Maybe it would be possible to tweak default marker to make it invisible (empty bitmap)... experiment. :)

```
 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow) {
    if(!shadow) {
     //my draw code
         }

    super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tmouse is correct. If you're overriding the ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.draw() method to draw your car with canvas, you'll need to add:

```
super.draw(canvas, view, shadow);
```

The super will setup and use the OverlayItem's Hotspot which is (from what I can see in the source) used as the touchable area for gestures.

However you'll still see the original Markers AND your canvas drawn ones. PLUS if you move your cars, the touchable area won't move with it. (the Hotspot will not be for the new location you drew at)

There are only 2 real solutions.

1) You re-implement ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.draw() and ItemizedOverlayWithFocus.onDrawItem() in your own ItemizedOverlayWithFocus class. (only you'll call onDrawItem(), onDrawCar(), and call it instead from the overridden draw() method)

That's not worth it unless you want to change the offset of the Marker being drawn. e.g. I have a tower icon, and I want 10 pixels from the bottom to be the Y point so it looks like the tower is standing on the GeoPoint, not at the edge of it.

2) You create your own Markers from a Bitmap first, and set it as a Drawable Marker in the OverlayItem.setMarker() method. Try creating a a Bitmap using Canvas:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// Draw on your car on the canvas...
```

Then try assigning the Bitmap:

```
overlayItem.setMarker(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

Don't override draw() unless you want to draw some other stuff, and if you do ensure you super.draw() so the Marker and its Hotspot work with the gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this code

```
Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker);

this.mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
            newMarker, "listener try null", new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getActivity()));

mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
```